# Proguard obfuscation when building from source

Tags: android, proguard, android-source

I'm trying to make proguard obfuscate my app when building AOSP from source.
When running in IntelliJ it works just fine, using the following proguard.flags:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.chromium.**
-dontwarn org.xwalk.core.**

-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

-keep class org.xwalk.core.** {
    *;
}
-keep class org.chromium.** {
    *;
}
-keepattributes **

-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
```

But when building the complete system, including my app, with the following Android.mk file, it doesn't work:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := DukaSharedLibrary\
                               DukaBrowserLibrary\
                               JsoupBrowserLibrary\
                               CrossWalkLibrary\
                               CommonsValidatorLibrary      


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files, src)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../../vendor/duka/CrossWalkCompatibility/org/xwalk/core/internal/R.java
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../../vendor/duka/CrossWalkCompatibility/org/chromium/content/R.java
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../../vendor/duka/CrossWalkCompatibility/org/chromium/ui/R.java
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += vendor/duka/DukaSharedLibrary/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += vendor/duka/DukaBrowserLibrary/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += vendor/duka/CrossWalk/res

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := DukaBrowser
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_ASSET_DIR := vendor/duka/DukaSharedLibrary/assets

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := JsoupBrowserLibrary:libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := CommonsValidatorLibrary:libs/commons-validator-1.4.0.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

When looking at the resulting .odex file (I'm building for TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT:=user) it's not obfuscated - but it is when doing the same thing in IntelliJ.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove the line withTARGET_BUILD_VARIANT entirely or use TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT:=aosp

Comment: @EyalBellisha Thanks. But it didn't work. Tried it both with aosp and no TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT.